# Merged cells in excel become NaN in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

How can I read excel file which has form like this into pandas DataFrame?

```
a       b   c    d       e    f
Type    1   22   Car     Yes  2019
                 Train   Yes  
Type    2   25   Car     No   2018
Notype  1        Car     Yes  2019
                 Train
```

First row has three columns that are merged cells (2 rows) however the rest are separate rows

The thing is if i use

```
data = pd.read_excel("excel.xls").fillna(method='ffill')
```

Then value `"25"` from third row and `"Yes"` from fourth row will fill NaN value below and that is not something I want. So every column that is merged should copy exact values for both rows. In this case `"a", "b", "c"` and `"f"` are merged columns

So correctly it should load like this:

```
a       b   c    d       e   f
Type    1   22   Car     Yes 2019
Type    1   22   Train   Yes 2019
Type    2   25   Car     No  2018
Notype  1   NaN  Car     Yes 2019
Notype  1   NaN  Train   NaN 2019
```

Comment: Is there a regularity on how these merged cells appear in the dataframe, that is different from "real" empty cells? I mean, if you just see the DF without knowledge of the excel file, can you tell whether this cell should be filled or not?

Comment: Only specific columns contain merged cells. I know which columns contain merged cells if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @jezrael I uploaded small sample of the data into google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/110n6gfvNrNo75ZxGTSz7gUq5Ps_MeQEWcD10l9LIPds/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @jezrael Try this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/110n6gfvNrNo75ZxGTSz7gUq5Ps_MeQEWcD10l9LIPds/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Create them in pandas DF?

Comment: In excel you can merge, unmerge them. I just want to load this sample file I shared on google docs onto a dataframe that does not change how the data is shaped in the excel file.

Comment: No this one value in one cell. It's just how this value looks like. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Actually I looked at the data again and it is possible to do ffil for all columns except one or two. Is it possibl to do forward fill of NaN values for all of them except 2 specific columns? I think that would be the best solution for my problem

Comment: Answer was edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need forward filling all columns with excluding some names from list use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) with forward filling missing values:

```
cols_excluded = ['c','e']
cols = df.columns.difference(cols_excluded)

df[cols] = df[cols].ffill()
print (df)
        a    b     c      d    e
0    Type  1.0  22.0    Car  Yes
1    Type  1.0   NaN  Train  Yes
2    Type  2.0  25.0    Car   No
3  Notype  1.0   NaN    Car  Yes
4  Notype  1.0   NaN  Train  NaN
```

Also if necessary forward filling all missing values with exlude last missing values per columns (here `cols_excluded`):

```
df[cols_excluded] = df[cols_excluded].where(df[cols_excluded].bfill().isna(),
                                            df[cols_excluded].ffill())
print (df)

        a    b     c      d    e
0    Type  1.0  22.0    Car  Yes
1    Type  1.0  22.0  Train  Yes
2    Type  2.0  25.0    Car   No
3  Notype  1.0   NaN    Car  Yes
4  Notype  1.0   NaN  Train  NaN
```

Comment: The second option works only for values which are last in the column? So for NaN in the middle it wouldnt work?

Comment: @AlexT - It omit only in last NaNs values in column, but all another missing values are replaced, if dont need it, remove `df[cols_excluded] = df[cols_excluded].where(df[cols_excluded].bfill().isna(),
                                            df[cols_excluded].ffill())`